# Return multiple values in a function in PHP

Tags: php

I am looking for a way to return multiple parameters in a function. I am building a routing system for my [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) framework. And currently I am working on a way to get unlimited arguments in a function, based on an HTTP request;

This is the part I am stuck on. Look on the bottom of the code
$controller->{$route->getMethod()}();

The controller calls a function, and now I need to get a solution to add values in de function. I can do $controller->{$route->getMethod()}($route->getArgs();

But then only the first argument will be set. How can I return more than one argument in that function?

```
public function dispatchRoute(Route $route)
{
    if(!file_exists($this->pathToController . '/' . ucfirst($route->getController()) . 'Controller.php'))
        throw new \Exception(
        sprintf('Cannot find %sController.php in directory %s', $route->getController(), $this->pathToController));

    require_once($this->pathToController . '/' . ucfirst($route->getController()) . 'Controller.php');

    $controller = $route->getController() . 'Controller';
    $controller = new $controller();

    if(!method_exists($controller, $route->getMethod()))
        throw new \Exception(sprintf('Method %s is not found in %sController', $route->getMethod(), $route->getController()));

    $dataHandler = new RequestDataHandler();
    $dataHandler->getRequestArguments();
    $controller->{$route->getMethod()}();
}
```

Comment: please clarify the question

Comment: i need multiple return of args IN function ($1, $2, $3),

Comment: It sounds as you want to pass your variables as references, http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: What does the backslash ("\") in `\Exception` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use

```
$data = $someclass->returnThreeValues();
foo($data[0], $data[1], $data[2];
```

or

```
list($p1, $p2, $p3) = $someClass->returnThreeValues();
foo($p1, $p2, $p3);
```

or (just to be complete, above options are preferred)

```
call_user_func_array('foo', $someClass->returnThreeValues());
```

And let

```
function returnThreeValues() {
    // Some code to calculate $a, $b, $c
    return array($a, $b, $c);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Return array.

```
function foo($bar1, $bar2, $bar3){
{
  return array($bar1, $bar2, $bar3);
}
```

Your example is not returning anything.. just printing.

Answer (score 0):

Find it

```
call_user_func_array(array($controller, $route->getMethod()), array($dataHandler->getRequestArguments()));
```